# Should I be using an IAuthorizationFilter if I wish to create an ApiKey restricted resource with ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have a few simple routes which I wish to restrict via a simple querystring param. If the key is incorrect or not provided, then I wish to throw a `NotAuthorizedException`.

Please don't suggest I use WebApi or the equiv - I can't just yet in this scenario.

So i'm not sure if I should be implementing an `IAuthorizationFilter` or implementing an `IActionFilter` or even something else.

My code logic?

- Check querystring for key.
- Check my RavenDb (repository) for a user with that key/value.

If they fail any of those checks, then throw the `NotAuthorizedException`.

I'm assuming I would then decorate a my action method with this filter. I'm also assuming i would need to pass in my repository into this action method also?

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> So i'm not sure if I should be implementing an IAuthorizationFilter or
>   implementing an IActionFilter or even something else.

You should be implementing an `IAuthorizationFilter`:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute: FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var key = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["param_name"];
        if (!IsValid(key))
        {
            // Unauthorized!
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }

    private bool IsValid(string key)
    {
        // You know what to do here => go hit your RavenDb
        // and perform the necessary checks
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And if you wanted to use dependency injection into your custom action filter you could take a look at the [`following article`](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/01/20/injectable-configurable-action-filters.aspx) in which you could implement a custom filter provider (`IFilterProvider`). You could have a marked attribute which you may use on controller actions and then have this custom filter provider simply look whether the action is decorated with this marker attribute and apply the custom authorization filter.

For example:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute: Attribute
{

}
```

and your authorization filter will only implement the `IAuthorizationFilter`, it won't be a `FilterAttribute`:

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter: IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly ISomeRepository repository;
    public class MyAuthorizationFilter(ISomeRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var key = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["param_name"];
        if (!IsValid(key))
        {
            // Unauthorized!
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }

    private bool IsValid(string key)
    {
        // You know what to do here => go hit your RavenDb
        // and perform the necessary checks
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then you will have the custom filter provider:

```
public class MyFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        if (actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAuthorizeAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            var filter = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<MyAuthorizationFilter>();
            yield return new Filter(filter, FilterScope.Global);
        }

        yield break;
    }
}
```

that will be registered in your `Application_Start`:

```
FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new MyFilterProvider());
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Darin! I noticed that you used Property Injection (I think that's what it's called) instead of Constructor Injection - is there any reason why I couldn't just do that in the `MyAuthorizationFilter` class .. and let the `MyAuthorizationFilter` also inherit the `FilterAttribute` ? Then I would only have 1 class, not 2 to make.

Comment: Nah, it's using constructor injection. That's what the `DependencyResolver` is doing in `MyFilterProvider`. I'm assuming you can't use a single class as the framework doesn't construct attributes using the DependencyResolver and as such, you couldn't decorate your actions with it because it needs a  `Repository` passed in to the constructor and you won't have one available. Is there any better way to do constructor injection on attributes as this implementation will make it quite hard to do things like `[MyAuthorize(ErrorMessage = "Sad panda")]`.

Comment: @ajbeaven You can make your attribute with parameters as you would, and then set them as internal properties and get the attribute from within the authorizationFilter to get access to its properties/fields. Use `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(YourClass), true).Cast<YourClass>();` to get the attribute. The internal scope is useful if you have a dedicated project for them; else, just make getters.