# How to create a custom attribute that will redirect to Login if it returns false, similar to the Authorize attribute - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried Googling a few things about custom attributes but I'm still not sure how to go about it....

I'm storing a few important details of the user in Session cookies (ex UserID) once the user log's in.. and all I want to do is create an attribute where if the

`if (Session["UserID"] == null)`

then it will redirect to login just like the [Authorize] attribute does.  That way I can apply this attribute on the Controller level everywhere.

Should I overwrite the Authorize attribute?  Create a new one?  How do I get it to redirect to login as well?

I'm also using ASP.NET MVC 4

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can certainly define custom authentication filters (ie types that implement [`IAuthorizationFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) but otherwise your question is very broad: you need to define far better what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry I'm not trying to get someone to code it for me, I guess I'm just looking for direction on what I should research specifically.

Comment: @Richard I think that's exactly what I needed.  So if I implement IAuthorizationFilter, if it fails, will that redirect to Login just like [Authorize]?  I guess that's what I'm most looking for.

Comment: Perhaps start by specifying why the built in filters (and Identity provider) do not meet your requirements?

Comment: @Richard I'm still pretty new to the ASP.NET environment.. What filters and Identity provider could I use to accomplish what I'm looking to do?  (Redirect to login for all controllers if a Session cookie is null.)  I just came up with the Attribute idea because it seems like it would be the best, but I would love to know an even better alternative.  Again not looking for someone to do code for me but just a direction on what to google..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` and override `AuthorizeCore()` and `HandleUnauthorizedRequest()` as required. Add your own logic which will do the check and redirect if necessary.

I'm just showing a simple example using MVC's `ActionFilterAttribute` (which is not the best place to do authentication/authorization)

```
public class VerifyUserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserID"];
        if (user == null)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(string.Format("/User/Login?targetUrl={0}",filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath));
    }
}
```

Do not forget to set the `Session["UserID"]` variable in your `/User/Login` action method after proper user validation.

Comment: Hey Thank you for this.  So pretty much all I need to look into is instead of taking in the ActionFilterAttribute, look into how do to do it for the AuthorizeAttribute and I should be good?  if that's correct, i got a good idea of what i need to do.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1189352 If you do not use Authorization headers and any other kind of standard validations, even this will work fine (just run and check once, I didn't). But I'd suggest to follow the standard practices of using AuthorizeAttribute, if you can.

Comment: I do use the Authorization headers.  I put [Authorize] for all my controllers (if that's what you mean).  Since that's the case, would it be better for me to look into overloading the Authorize attribute instead?

Comment: I was talking about Authorization http headers. But, f you are already using [Authorize] attribute on your controllers, then you are using some authorization already. Since you are new to MVC, you can [1] First use this code as is [2] Study about MVC authorize filters, and later move to `AuthorizeAttribute` when you know how to use it.

Comment: thank you for the tips.  i really appreciate that.  i'm more into learning than just trying to copy some code.. ty!

Comment: WC. For now, you can copy this code and work :) You can use code from the other answer (using IAuthorizationFilter) as well. Before using understand the code, so that you can fix it in case there are any issues.

Answer (score 10):

You can create your own version of the [`Authorize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute by implementing the [`IAuthorizationFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) interface. Here's an example:

```
class MyCustomFilter : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserID"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/");
        }
    }
}
```

and a usage example:

```
[MyCustomFilter]
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that dependency injection will not be possible through constructor doing like that. If you need DI, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708942/should-i-be-using-an-iauthorizationfilter-if-i-wish-to-create-an-apikey-restrict

Comment: This looks promising I'll try it when I get home thanks!