# Restricting access to controller actions for non logged in users in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I'm quite new to MVC. I used to work with classical ASP.NET (Web forms). In web forms, whenever I'd have to restrict someone access to specific ASPX pages, I'd put them in a specific folder (lets call it a User folder) with a web.config file that looks something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>  
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Which basically redirects user to login page if hes not authenticated...

Now I have a MVC 4 application in which I have folder for all of the controllers... How would I restrict access to specific actions within controller.. Lets call it UserController, so that whenever user tries to access those specific actions within that controller, he'd be prompted to the login page... If hes authenticated, then he can access those resources...

Can someone help me out with this ??

P.S. Is there any way that I can  assign a specific role for that User type when he logs in ?? Lets say the user type is "Worker", and I don't want anyone else but that user type to be able to access the controller besides that role, if they are authenticated of course...

Comment: Use the `[Authorize]` attribute

Comment: Okay ty, can you read my edited question, its related to user roles...

Comment: Then use `[Authorize(Roles="...")]`

Comment: Okay but how will I assign the role to the user when he logs in?? Plus, where can I specify to which page will user be redirected if hes not authenticated??

Comment: Your login system should link to a database which should contain an AspNetUsersRoles table, here you can link user to custom roles.

Answer (score 3):

you simply use the Asp.Net `[Authorize]`Data Annotations to restrict unlogged users. below code is the default one

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   your code
}
```

if you want specific user to access the controller, you have to use the `Roles` along with `[Authorize]`

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute here. By attribute check you can do that easily.

This is my attribute class.

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited=true, AllowMultiple=true)]
public class AdminAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly bool _dontValidate;


    public AdminAuthorizeAttribute()
        : this(false)
    {
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (IsAdminPageRequested(filterContext))
        {
            if (!this.HasAdminAccess(filterContext))
                this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

    public virtual bool HasAdminAccess(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var permissionService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IPermissionService>();
        bool result = permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.AccessAdminPanel);
        return result;
    }
}
```

this is my controller class.

```
    [AdminAuthorize]
    public class WidgetsLikeController : BasePluginController
    {
```

or you can use it before an action

```
    [AdminAuthorize]
    public ActionResult AdminLike()
    {
        return View("~/Plugins/Widgets.Like/Views/WidgetsLike/AdminLike.cshtml");
    }
```

[It will also help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925219/how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-that-will-redirect-to-login-if-it-returns-false/32925506)