# .Net Core Use Session in Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using Session in .Net core, However i am able to set and get the Session data in Controller like

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("User", "True");
var user = HttpContext.Session.GetString("User");
```

But when i am trying to use the same code in a concrete class i am not able to do so. It does not show **GetString** or **SetString** after  **HttpContext.Session**.

It does not work after

```
HttpContext.Session
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: The context is held in the controller class only, if you need session info within a model class, pass the session object as a parameter of a method of your class via a controller. Otherwise your are kind of breaking the design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `HttpContext` is a member of `Controller`, and outside a controller, it's a type name. See [Access the current HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-the-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core) how to inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into a class and access the session from there.

However, it's generally inadvisable to use the session in a class library. You'd better pass the particular *values* to your library call. So instead of accessing the settings in the library method, you do:

```
// controller code

var user = HttpContext.Session.GetString("User");
var libraryResult = _fooLibrary.Bar(user);
HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserResult", libraryResult);
```

Comment: Actually i am trying to check the session in a custom ClaimRequirementFilter. So from a central location i want to check the session. I mean if the session is found then give the access to user else show unotherised page.

Comment: Umm so why didn't you begin by explaining that? You can just [access `filterContext.HttpContext.Session` in `OnActionExecuting()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925219/how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-that-will-redirect-to-login-if-it-returns-false).

Comment: Oh ! my :) that was so easy.. Thanks Man!

Answer (score 8):

To access session in non-controller class -

1. First, register the following service in Startup.ConfigureServices

   ```
     services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
   ```
2. Now, register a class (example - SessionManager) where you want to access the Session in Startup.ConfigureServices.

   ```
     services.AddScoped<SessionManager>();
   ```
3. Now, in SessionManager class, add the following code.

   ```
     private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;    
     private readonly ISession _session;    
     public SessionManager(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)    
     {    
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;    
            _session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;    
      }
   ```

The above code is receiving IHttpContextAccessor object through dependency injection and then, it is storing Sessions in a local variable.