# Run code when action is called in specific controller asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Say for example I have an admin controller and I want to perform additional custom checks when the user who calls any of the actions of the admin controller.

How do I execute some code within the controller class when any action is called for the controller only?

Comment: add an `AuthorizeAttribute` or a custom AuthorizeAttribute above the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not asking for a specific programming example I will just refer you to the .net core documentation of [Service Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#servicefilterattribute).

I have used these before to create something like an activity tracker for logged in users, so say it was an admin, and I wanted to see how long ago the user has performed an action, this filter would check the users last activity in a session before allowing access to the method.

Here is a generic example:

```
public class MyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public MyFilter()
    {
    }

    //After Method execution
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }

    //Before Method execution
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

In Startup: `services.AddScoped<MyFilter>();`

And above controller/action: `[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyFilter))]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify user when accessing any method withing the controller, decorate your controller with `[Authorize]` attribute.

If you want to restrict only certain actions, you could leave your controller as is and just decorate desired methods with `[Authorize]` attribute.

If you wish to leave only certain methods unauthorized within controller, decorate controller with `[Authorize]` attribute, and the methods that you want to be accessed by anonymous users will need to be decorated using `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

Would this help? If you have specific requirements, please include them in question.

Comment: I guess that example is not a good one to use. I would just like to execute a method whenever an action within a specific controller is called then have it continue on into the action.

Comment: Ah, I see. Do you want to perform certain action prior to your controller ‘s method execution? If that is what you’re after, you could probably get away with custom filter attributes. What sort of method / action do you want to perform prior to standard method?

Comment: I just want to retrieve a string using HttpContext.Session.Get and check if it is null or empty.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you then want to use the string in your controller’s action? Or just want to perform a null or empty check on string? Also, based on the outcome of the test, what would you want to do further?

Comment: Just to perform a null or empty check on the string. It should redirect me to another action within the controller if null or empty. Otherwise, it will continue into the action that was called.

Comment: Perhaps this SO answer is what you need - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32925355/4794396. Check if that helps, if not, I’ll write a code for you once I get access to computer (probably in couple of hours)

Comment: Unfortunately, that does work for me as the technology being used in that question is ASP.NET and not ASP.NET Core. I have tried implementing something similar but my `ActionExecutingContext` always ends up being null when it is called.

Comment: In that case, could you update your question with what you tried and I will look into that soon.

Comment: Nevermind, I have found the issue. A clean + rebuild fixed it. It works fine now. Thank you! (How do I go about marking the correct answer given your answer is older? Sorry, im kind of new)

Comment: Glad, you found a solution. Whenever you feel the answer / post was helpful, you could vote up by pressing the up arrow. And to accept the answer, you click the grey arrow next to the answer (only the questioner can mark answer accepted). Have a read of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to know more about this.