# Is it possible to create middleware in ASP.NET Web API? I referred to info on the internet and tried, but did not work out

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I created table in SQL Server that contains user Id, user Name, user Password and user Role. When user logs in via ASP.NET web application program interface it will authenticate and create JSON Web Token and allow user to next page based on that token also its working good.

But now I need to add middleware in ASP.NET web application program interface and it should deny the user if its role is not meet the particular route access.

Is that possible? (front-end is react java script).

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. If you have experienced a problem getting it working, then please ask a new question giving details of what you're trying to do, what you have tried and what problems you have encountered.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple ways to do this. One is using an [Action Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs). There is [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16709042/1202807) of how to do that. This allows you to limit this to only certain actions, since you have to specify the attribute on each action or controller that you want it to apply to.

If you want it to apply to any request, you can do this in `Global.asax.cs`. If you want code to run at the beginning of every request, then put your code in `Application_BeginRequest`. Since you're looking at user access, you could use `Session_OnStart` instead, which runs once when a user first begins their session.

You can modify the `Response` directly and call [`Response.Flush()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.flush) and [`CompleteRequest()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest) to send the response and end the request.

```
protected void Session_OnStart() {
    //runs once at the beginning of each session

    if (/* I don't like you for some reason */) {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.StatusCode = 403;
        Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
        CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution
    }
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //do something at the start of every request
}
```

Comment: I have another doubt, i hosted reactjs and web api to my iis server. It's working fine to my machine, i can login and add, edit, delete details (used sql server database). But when i try to login from other machine which is connected to LAN i am unable to login. Getting network error. I can see Reactjs and web api from other machine. I think when i try to login It's unable to fetch details from sql server so can't login. What to do for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @selvan That sounds like a different problem. You can start a new question for that if you need to. You will have to address that network issue.